# Android ListActivity - fixed header and footer

Tags: android, header, footer, listactivity, fixed

Is it possible to set header and footer at ListActivity to be fixed at the top and the bottom, so only the content (list) is scrolling, not also header and footer?

I have both set like this:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.addHeaderView(header);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve it by using a custom XML layout in which you will set the layout of your header, footer and list.

Note that to be compatible with `ListActivity` this layout must contain a `ListView` with the id `android.R.id.list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HEADER" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FOOTER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And set it in your `ListActivity` like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to project scenario, this methodology would be better than any other approach, because if you want to customize the header and footer, you can make changes in appropriate header and footer layout.
In your layout xml file follow this :

### In main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <include
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header.xml" />

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:below="@id/header_layout"
        android:above="@id/footer_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/footer.xml" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

### In header.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/header_text_view"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="Your Application Title"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

### In footer.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <Button
           android:id="@+id/done_button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="Done"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

### In Activity, Here

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

   private ListView mListView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        // Now you can do whatever you want

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way given below:

```
    //your adapter for listview
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    // TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    //text view or whatever you have for your footer
    TextView footerView = null;
    footerView=(TextView)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view,null);

    // TODO - Add footerView to ListView

    getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
    getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

This is inside of your onCreate() method. It worked for me. give comments if you find any bugs here