# i just want to clear this code out

Tags: android

I've tried to make this code but i got an error in the part where the header and footer     is suppose to load..i got this from this post   [Android ListActivity - fixed header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401760/android-listactivity-fixed-header-and-footer) im just checking hoping this will not lead people to wrong codes...the error says 
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'above' in package 'android'
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'below'in package 'android'

or i just got it all wrong ignore it when im wrong

```
 In main.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <include
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header.xml" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:below="@id/header_layout"
    android:above="@id/footer_layout" />

   <include
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/footer.xml" />
  </RelativeLayout>
In header.xml

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/header_text_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="Your Application Title"/>
 </LinearLayout>
In footer.xml`enter code here`

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button
       android:id="@+id/done_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:text="Done"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

In Activity, Here

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

 private ListView mListView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    // Now you can do whatever you want

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `android:below` to `android:layout_below` and `android:above` to `android:layout_above` in your main.xml

**EDIT**:
There are other ways to accomplish this that will probably work better.

*Option A*: User a vertical LinearLayout instead. Notice the layout attributes for the listview; these will allow it to stretch to fill up the space not taken by the header and footer views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header.xml" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/footer.xml" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*Option B*: ListActivity automatically provides a ListView for you if you don't call `setContentView()`. In this case you would create or inflate the header and footer views yourself and add them to the listview in code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    super(saved);
    ListView list = getListView();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, list, false);
    View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, list, false);

    // these must be called before list.setAdapter()
    list.addHeaderView(headerView);
    list.addFooterView(footerView);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Also, since you are using ListActvity, your ListView element should have `android:id="@android:id/list"`. In your activity, you would use `mListView = getListView();`

Comment: why is it that the header still has an error the id is the same header but he keeps saying no resource found so wierd....

Comment: seriously?is this code for header and footer why did my result show in the center lol stupid i cant make it right..

Comment: Personally, I would do this differently. **Option A**: Use a vertical LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout. Keep the order of the views, but make the ListView have `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`. **Option B**: don't use a layout at all. ListActivity already provides a ListView for you automatically if you don't call `setContentView()`. You will have to programmatically add your header and footer views before setting the list adapter.

Comment: can you make it a bit clearer?like showing in code poor english and poor progaramming android skills just started programing last month..still learning