# Make design in android

Tags: android, xml

I have problem to make design like this

example Image :

[image]

with in top content and bottom list view please help

how to make content in top?

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"      
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView     
            android:id="@+id/list_image"   
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

    <!-- Rightend Duration -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

     <!-- Rightend Arrow -->    
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i used http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Use relative layout and set margins and weight properties in your xml. Try to share some code what you have tried here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Relativlayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Use android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

[Android ListActivity - fixed header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401760/android-listactivity-fixed-header-and-footer)